# Can not get SDL2 to display anything more than glClearColor

Tags: c++, opengl, sdl

I have followed a couple of tutorials, examples:

- http://lazyfoo.net/tutorials/SDL/51_SDL_and_modern_opengl/
- https://gist.github.com/olevegard/e1ce53d9302c4ed3be8d#file-simple-opengl-test-cpp

However, I can not get it to render anything more than solid color using `glClearColor` (tried it on MacOS and Linux).

Here is what I have at the moment which is a simple cmake with modified example of lazyfoo to get it compiled (only path of headers are changed):

```c++
/*This source code copyrighted by Lazy Foo' Productions (2004-2015)
and may not be redistributed without written permission.*/

//Using SDL, SDL OpenGL, GLEW, standard IO, and strings
#include <SDL2/SDL.h>
#include <GL/glew.h>
#include <SDL2/SDL_opengl.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string>


//Screen dimension constants
const int SCREEN_WIDTH = 640;
const int SCREEN_HEIGHT = 480;

//Starts up SDL, creates window, and initializes OpenGL
bool init();

//Initializes rendering program and clear color
bool initGL();

//Input handler
void handleKeys( unsigned char key, int x, int y );

//Per frame update
void update();

//Renders quad to the screen
void render();

//Frees media and shuts down SDL
void close();

//Shader loading utility programs
void printProgramLog( GLuint program );
void printShaderLog( GLuint shader );

//The window we'll be rendering to
SDL_Window* gWindow = NULL;

//OpenGL context
SDL_GLContext gContext;

//Render flag
bool gRenderQuad = true;

//Graphics program
GLuint gProgramID = 0;
GLint gVertexPos2DLocation = -1;
GLuint gVBO = 0;
GLuint gIBO = 0;

bool init()
{
    //Initialization flag
    bool success = true;

    //Initialize SDL
    if( SDL_Init( SDL_INIT_VIDEO ) < 0 )
    {
        printf( "SDL could not initialize! SDL Error: %s\n", SDL_GetError() );
        success = false;
    }
    else
    {
        //Use OpenGL 3.1 core
        SDL_GL_SetAttribute( SDL_GL_CONTEXT_MAJOR_VERSION, 3 );
        SDL_GL_SetAttribute( SDL_GL_CONTEXT_MINOR_VERSION, 1 );
        SDL_GL_SetAttribute( SDL_GL_CONTEXT_PROFILE_MASK, SDL_GL_CONTEXT_PROFILE_CORE );

        //Create window
        gWindow = SDL_CreateWindow( "SDL Tutorial", SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED, SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED, SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT, SDL_WINDOW_OPENGL | SDL_WINDOW_SHOWN );
        if( gWindow == NULL )
        {
            printf( "Window could not be created! SDL Error: %s\n", SDL_GetError() );
            success = false;
        }
        else
        {
            //Create context
            gContext = SDL_GL_CreateContext( gWindow );
            if( gContext == NULL )
            {
                printf( "OpenGL context could not be created! SDL Error: %s\n", SDL_GetError() );
                success = false;
            }
            else
            {
                //Initialize GLEW
                glewExperimental = GL_TRUE; 
                GLenum glewError = glewInit();
                if( glewError != GLEW_OK )
                {
                    printf( "Error initializing GLEW! %s\n", glewGetErrorString( glewError ) );
                }

                //Use Vsync
                if( SDL_GL_SetSwapInterval( 1 ) < 0 )
                {
                    printf( "Warning: Unable to set VSync! SDL Error: %s\n", SDL_GetError() );
                }

                //Initialize OpenGL
                if( !initGL() )
                {
                    printf( "Unable to initialize OpenGL!\n" );
                    success = false;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    return success;
}

bool initGL()
{
    //Success flag
    bool success = true;

    //Generate program
    gProgramID = glCreateProgram();

    //Create vertex shader
    GLuint vertexShader = glCreateShader( GL_VERTEX_SHADER );

    //Get vertex source
    const GLchar* vertexShaderSource[] =
    {
        "#version 140\nin vec2 LVertexPos2D; void main() { gl_Position = vec4( LVertexPos2D.x, LVertexPos2D.y, 0, 1 ); }"
    };

    //Set vertex source
    glShaderSource( vertexShader, 1, vertexShaderSource, NULL );

    //Compile vertex source
    glCompileShader( vertexShader );

    //Check vertex shader for errors
    GLint vShaderCompiled = GL_FALSE;
    glGetShaderiv( vertexShader, GL_COMPILE_STATUS, &vShaderCompiled );
    if( vShaderCompiled != GL_TRUE )
    {
        printf( "Unable to compile vertex shader %d!\n", vertexShader );
        printShaderLog( vertexShader );
        success = false;
    }
    else
    {
        //Attach vertex shader to program
        glAttachShader( gProgramID, vertexShader );


        //Create fragment shader
        GLuint fragmentShader = glCreateShader( GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER );

        //Get fragment source
        const GLchar* fragmentShaderSource[] =
        {
            "#version 140\nout vec4 LFragment; void main() { LFragment = vec4( 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0 ); }"
        };

        //Set fragment source
        glShaderSource( fragmentShader, 1, fragmentShaderSource, NULL );

        //Compile fragment source
        glCompileShader( fragmentShader );

        //Check fragment shader for errors
        GLint fShaderCompiled = GL_FALSE;
        glGetShaderiv( fragmentShader, GL_COMPILE_STATUS, &fShaderCompiled );
        if( fShaderCompiled != GL_TRUE )
        {
            printf( "Unable to compile fragment shader %d!\n", fragmentShader );
            printShaderLog( fragmentShader );
            success = false;
        }
        else
        {
            //Attach fragment shader to program
            glAttachShader( gProgramID, fragmentShader );


            //Link program
            glLinkProgram( gProgramID );

            //Check for errors
            GLint programSuccess = GL_TRUE;
            glGetProgramiv( gProgramID, GL_LINK_STATUS, &programSuccess );
            if( programSuccess != GL_TRUE )
            {
                printf( "Error linking program %d!\n", gProgramID );
                printProgramLog( gProgramID );
                success = false;
            }
            else
            {
                //Get vertex attribute location
                gVertexPos2DLocation = glGetAttribLocation( gProgramID, "LVertexPos2D" );
                if( gVertexPos2DLocation == -1 )
                {
                    printf( "LVertexPos2D is not a valid glsl program variable!\n" );
                    success = false;
                }
                else
                {
                    //Initialize clear color
                    glClearColor( 0.f, 0.f, 0.f, 1.f );

                    //VBO data
                    GLfloat vertexData[] =
                    {
                        -0.5f, -0.5f,
                         0.5f, -0.5f,
                         0.5f,  0.5f,
                        -0.5f,  0.5f
                    };

                    //IBO data
                    GLuint indexData[] = { 0, 1, 2, 3 };

                    //Create VBO
                    glGenBuffers( 1, &gVBO );
                    glBindBuffer( GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, gVBO );
                    glBufferData( GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 2 * 4 * sizeof(GLfloat), vertexData, GL_STATIC_DRAW );

                    //Create IBO
                    glGenBuffers( 1, &gIBO );
                    glBindBuffer( GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, gIBO );
                    glBufferData( GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, 4 * sizeof(GLuint), indexData, GL_STATIC_DRAW );
                }
            }
        }
    }

    return success;
}

void handleKeys( unsigned char key, int x, int y )
{
    //Toggle quad
    if( key == 'q' )
    {
        gRenderQuad = !gRenderQuad;
    }
}

void update()
{
    //No per frame update needed
}

void render()
{
    //Clear color buffer
    glClear( GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT );

    //Render quad
    if( gRenderQuad )
    {
        //Bind program
        glUseProgram( gProgramID );

        //Enable vertex position
        glEnableVertexAttribArray( gVertexPos2DLocation );

        //Set vertex data
        glBindBuffer( GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, gVBO );
        glVertexAttribPointer( gVertexPos2DLocation, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 2 * sizeof(GLfloat), NULL );

        //Set index data and render
        glBindBuffer( GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, gIBO );
        glDrawElements( GL_TRIANGLE_FAN, 4, GL_UNSIGNED_INT, NULL );

        //Disable vertex position
        glDisableVertexAttribArray( gVertexPos2DLocation );

        //Unbind program
        glUseProgram( NULL );
    }
}

void close()
{
    //Deallocate program
    glDeleteProgram( gProgramID );

    //Destroy window    
    SDL_DestroyWindow( gWindow );
    gWindow = NULL;

    //Quit SDL subsystems
    SDL_Quit();
}

void printProgramLog( GLuint program )
{
    //Make sure name is shader
    if( glIsProgram( program ) )
    {
        //Program log length
        int infoLogLength = 0;
        int maxLength = infoLogLength;

        //Get info string length
        glGetProgramiv( program, GL_INFO_LOG_LENGTH, &maxLength );

        //Allocate string
        char* infoLog = new char[ maxLength ];

        //Get info log
        glGetProgramInfoLog( program, maxLength, &infoLogLength, infoLog );
        if( infoLogLength > 0 )
        {
            //Print Log
            printf( "%s\n", infoLog );
        }

        //Deallocate string
        delete[] infoLog;
    }
    else
    {
        printf( "Name %d is not a program\n", program );
    }
}

void printShaderLog( GLuint shader )
{
    //Make sure name is shader
    if( glIsShader( shader ) )
    {
        //Shader log length
        int infoLogLength = 0;
        int maxLength = infoLogLength;

        //Get info string length
        glGetShaderiv( shader, GL_INFO_LOG_LENGTH, &maxLength );

        //Allocate string
        char* infoLog = new char[ maxLength ];

        //Get info log
        glGetShaderInfoLog( shader, maxLength, &infoLogLength, infoLog );
        if( infoLogLength > 0 )
        {
            //Print Log
            printf( "%s\n", infoLog );
        }

        //Deallocate string
        delete[] infoLog;
    }
    else
    {
        printf( "Name %d is not a shader\n", shader );
    }
}

int main( int argc, char* args[] )
{
    //Start up SDL and create window
    if( !init() )
    {
        printf( "Failed to initialize!\n" );
    }
    else
    {
        //Main loop flag
        bool quit = false;

        //Event handler
        SDL_Event e;

        //Enable text input
        SDL_StartTextInput();

        //While application is running
        while( !quit )
        {
            //Handle events on queue
            while( SDL_PollEvent( &e ) != 0 )
            {
                //User requests quit
                if( e.type == SDL_QUIT )
                {
                    quit = true;
                }
                //Handle keypress with current mouse position
                else if( e.type == SDL_TEXTINPUT )
                {
                    int x = 0, y = 0;
                    SDL_GetMouseState( &x, &y );
                    handleKeys( e.text.text[ 0 ], x, y );
                }
            }

            //Render quad
            render();

            //Update screen
            SDL_GL_SwapWindow( gWindow );
        }

        //Disable text input
        SDL_StopTextInput();
    }

    //Free resources and close SDL
    close();

    return 0;
}
```

CMakeLists.txt:

```cmake
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.6)
project(wrench)
find_package(PkgConfig REQUIRED)

## PROJECT

set(PROJECT_NAME "wrench")

# for threading we need c11 std.
add_definitions("-std=c++11")

# source files go in src directory.
file(GLOB_RECURSE ${PROJECT_NAME}_SOURCES "${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/src/*.cpp")
add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME} ${wrench_SOURCES})

# headers are placed along the source files and vendor directory can be used to
# have other libraries like LuaBridge.
include_directories(
  "src"
  "vendor"
)

## LIBRARIES

# Lua
find_package(Lua51 REQUIRED)
include_directories(${LUA_INCLUDE_DIR})
target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} ${LUA_LIBRARIES})

# OpenGL
find_package(OpenGL REQUIRED)
include_directories(${OpenGL_INCLUDE_DIR})
target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} ${OPENGL_LIBRARIES})

# GLEW
find_package(GLEW REQUIRED)
include_directories(${GLEW_INCLUDE_DIRS})
target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} ${GLEW_LIBRARIES})

# SDL2
find_package(SDL2 REQUIRED)
include_directories(${SDL2_INCLUDE_DIRS})
target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} ${SDL2_LIBRARIES})
pkg_search_module(SDL2_image REQUIRED SDL2_image)
target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} ${SDL2_image_LIBRARIES})

# BOOST
find_package(Boost 1.62.0 COMPONENTS filesystem system)
include_directories(${Boost_INCLUDE_DIRS})
target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} ${Boost_LIBRARIES})
```

It is supposed to render a quad but all I get is a black screen:

[image: blackscreen SDL2 - lazyfoo tutorial]

Any suggestions what could be the problem here?

Comment: Did you forget to bind a VAO?

Comment: @immibis as far as I can tell, no. Indices and vertexes are loaded and bound. There is no color attribute though because the fragment shader is literally using solid white.

Comment: That has nothing to do with whether you're creating and binding a VAO, which it seems you aren't...

Comment: @immibis as you have noticed, I am following a tutorial here so my knowledge is very limited. Based on what I understand and did before (http://pastebin.com/UGSAbdrx), what I have here should be enough. Could you be more specific about what I need to do or guide me to the right path?

Comment: You need to call glGenVertexArrays to create a VAO and glBindVertexArray to bind it. Do this before binding any buffers. If you aren't using VAOs for your own purposes, you don't need to do anything else. I'm surprised the tutorial didn't mention it. (Note that a VAO is a badly-named object that's *not* the actual array of vertex data)

Comment: @immibis thanks. Indeed that was the problem.